# how to fix this jsoup element nullpointerexception

Tags: java, jsoup

UPDATE: Thanks everyone accepted zEro answer it seemed to fix my problem and is nice and neat.

Hey everyone I am doing some work with jsoup at the moment and am scraping some data from pages...

I seem to be having an issue where this block of code throws a nullpointerexception

```
Element imagelink;
imagelink = post.getElementsByClass("separator").first().getElementsByTag("img").first();
if(imagelink != null){
if(imagelink.attr("src") != null){
imageURL = imagelink.attr("src");
}else{
imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";    
}
}else{
imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";
}                           }`
```

I have tried to condition the statements as to avoid a null pointer, but I can't seem to get rid of it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Update:

This seems to be due to the page I am scraping having very sloppy HTML some tags are there and some tags are not...

to fix this I had to run a lot of trapping to make sure all elements existed... I have come up with this but would love if some one can see a simplified way of writing it. (as I am fairly new to java)

```
Element imagelink;
                        imagelink = post.getElementsByClass("separator").first();
                        if(imagelink != null){
                            imagelink = imagelink.getElementsByTag("img").first();
                            if(imagelink !=null){
                                if(imagelink.attr("src") != null){
                                    imageURL = imagelink.attr("src");
                                }else{
                                    imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";
                                }
                            }else{
                                imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";    
                            }
                        }else{
                            imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";
                        }
```

Comment: Whats the line in where the exception is thrown?

Comment: You have too much method chaining, especially when you need to debug a NPE. Try to separate out your code a bit and use whitespace to your advantage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I believe it is with imagelink = post.getElementsByClass("separator").first().getElementsByTag("img").first(); would this be due to the method chaining as you mentioned?

Comment: It's not "due to method chaining", but rather method chaining makes debugging the error much more difficult. Put each method on its own line and then isolate, find and be able to correct the error.

Comment: The problem seems: Either `post` is `null`; or you don't have an element with the class `separator` **inside `post`**; or you don't have an `img` element **inside the first element with class `separator` inside `post`**. Does this help´? Anyway, can you show us the HTML of the page (or the page itself) you are trying to parse?

Comment: @user2307545 if it worked, do you mind also upvoting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String imageURL;

if(post == null || post.select(".separator img[src]").isEmpty())
    imageURL = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1209/k0ve.jpg";
else
    imageURL = post.select(".separator img[src]").first().attr("src");
```

Read up more on the [Jsoup selector syntax here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).